# Eclipse 4 Application doesn't show my View

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I follow the book "Instant Eclipse 4 RCP Development How-to" and try to build the example application.
But the view I created just don't show up.

This is my code for one of the views:

```
package codesnippetapp.views;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class SnippetListView {

    TableViewer snippetsList;

    @Inject
    public SnippetListView() {
        //TODO Your code here
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent){
        snippetsList = new TableViewer (parent);
    }

}
```

I created this class from the wizard from Application.e4xmi, so it is connected there.

I also dowloaded the files from the books website (http://www.packtpub.com/support/12481), and still can't see the view.

What else can I check? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: You need to specify the -clearPersistedState argument when you run the RCP in Eclipse to make sure it picks up changes in the Application.e4xmi.

Comment: I did that, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I found the answer by googeling: I had to import javax.annotation as a package as explained in this article: http://blog.vogella.com/2012/11/23/eclipse4-and-postconstruct-and-predestroy-not-called-javax-annotation.